# How to show some sets below to a $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F}$

Tags: probability

Let $A$ and $B$ belong to some $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F}$.

How would I show that $A\cap B,$ $  A\setminus B $ and $A \Delta B:=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$ below to $\mathcal{F}$ as well and

how would I find $P(A \Delta B)$ in terms on $P(A)$, $P(B)$ and $P(A \cap B)$ ?

So i have figured out the first part now using de-morgans law, but how do i figure out the second part of finding $P(A \Delta B)$ in terms of $P(A)$ ect? What does it mean by in terms of P(A)?

Any help would be much appreciated as I am revising for an exam and these types of questions seem to come up a lot!

Many thanks

Comment: What is $P$? You write $$P(A\mathbin{\triangle}B)=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)\;,$$ but in fact $$A\mathbin{\triangle}B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)\;.$$

Comment: Sorry you are correct i didnt mean to do that! I have edited the question now.

Comment: That helps, but what’s $P$? Power set?

Comment: Probability, so probability of $(A \Delta B)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra#Definition_and_properties), being closed under countable union and complement implies the closedness under countable intersection (why?). Also note that $A \setminus B=A \cap B^c$ which is in $\mathcal{F}$ since $B^c \in \mathcal{F}.$ Similarly $B \setminus A \in \mathcal{F},$ so does the union $(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A).$

For the second question, note that $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$ and replace $A$ by $A \setminus B$ and $B$ by $B \setminus A$ to get $P(A \Delta B)=P(A \setminus B)+P(B \setminus A)$ since $(A \setminus B) \cap (B \setminus A)=\emptyset.$